# handling textview's width with screen rotation xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android, textview, screen-orientation, horizontalscrollview

I have created a Xamarin.android app with listview inside a horizontalScrollView. I added  `[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]` to handle screen rotation. but what I realized is that my horizontalScrollView doesn't expand when screen is rotated horizontally so I added this  `android:fillViewport="true"`. it worked. but my textviews' widths remained the same. so I guessed it's because I have fixed width values for my textviews. I looked things up and finally came up with determining a weightsum for my linearlayout and weights for my textviews. this is my code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
<LinearLayout 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         
        >
        <Toolbar
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1" >
            <SearchView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/searchView1" />

            </Toolbar>
   
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/customselector"
   android:padding="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

            <TextView
        android:text="Text"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
     
    android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
   <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
     android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/> 
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
     
    android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/> 

     <TextView
        android:text="Text"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView3"
     
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/> 
       
    <TextView
          
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView4"
    
            android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            /> 
            </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            
    />
        <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView6" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I chose weightsum=10 because I want my textviews' width to be big enough. so I thought I could view the rest of my textviews by scrolling. but the scrollview stopped working. why is that? what do I do?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested the code you provided. It works well on my side. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/g2lDAH5

Comment: are you sure sir that you didn't change anything, because without ```android:fillViewport="true"``` the textviews stay crowded next to each other and don't take the space as expected, and with it the horizontalscrollview doesn't work for me